# Wrong class type with offline HTML-files for processing through beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to parse HTML-files using BeautifulSoup and python. The files are downloads from HTML-sites, so they are offline. One is for example the source code of this page: http://forum.pcgames.de/offizielle-ankuendigungen/9332445-videoforen-unterbereich-jetzt-geoeffnet-print.html

Instead of parsing the files, an AttributeError `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'text'`appears. I assume they variable `page` has the wrong class type. How can I make the variable able to be processed with Beautifulsoup?

I compared the process to HTML-sites that are downloaded in the script using request. It seems that they have the different class type `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`.
The class type of the variable `page` (see below) is `<class 'str'>`.

I open the file in python using

```
path = open('test.html', 'r')
page = path.read()
path.close
```

I try to process Beautifulsoup's HTML-parser on it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

The following error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I did not expect an error in this code line. There should actually not be an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a string to work with. Pass the `page` variable direct.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
path = open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Videoforen-Unterbereich jetzt geöffnet.html', 'r')  #path = open(r'test.html', 'r')
page = path.read()
path.close

soup = bs(page, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

I would use a `with` syntax though, to handle closure, and use `codecs` to keep the special characters encoding:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import codecs

path = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Videoforen-Unterbereich jetzt geöffnet.html'
with codecs.open(path, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    page = f.read()    
soup = bs(page, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```